Extend AppSync API in Amplify Gen2 to support field level resolvers
In Amplify Gen2 you can define a model or a customType - models are always linked to DynamoDB and customTypes are not linked to a datasource - however you can add a new one but this can only be resolved by a queryHandler. Taking the following example:
const schema = a.schema({
  Ticker: a.customType({
     latestPrice: a.string()
  }),
  Stock: a.model({
    ticker: a.string().required(),
    averagePrice: a.integer().required(),
    currency: a.string().required(),
    liveTicker: ref('Ticker')
  })
});
     

If I wanted the liveTicker value to have a customResolver at the field level which went to a Lambda to get the latestPrice of the ticker what is the best way to achieve this in Amplify Gen 2
I've tried to extend with CDK, but I can't find any useful info myself how this would be used to solve the above use case.
Alternatively I could take the liveTicker info out the model and do 2 calls one for the Stock and then get the live data after - or get both in one Lambda (with a custom Query) - but before doing that wanted to see if above is achievable?

I'm working this same problem now.  Any progress on your end?
